# Trying two use two files in one javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, readfile

I am trying to get two files (one XML and another TXT). I have tried making two XMLhttpRequests to grab the files and then get their responseXML and responeText returns.

To make the example easier I made it so I am trying to just pull two seperate text files and then add two of their lines containing a single number. Each text file `'filetestX.txt'` is just a text file containing the number 1 to 7 seperated by a line i.e

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Here is my code:

```
function testFiles(){

    var FILE1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    FILE1.open("GET", 'filetest1.txt', true);
    FILE1.send();
    FTEXT1 = (FILE1.responseText);

    var FILE2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    FILE2.open("GET", 'filetest2.txt', true);
    FILE2.send();
    FTEXT2 = (FILE1.responseText);

    // split each line to get the numbers 
    var split1 = FTEXT1.split('\n');
    var split2 = FTEXT2.split('\n');

    output = split1[2] + split2[3];

    console.log(output)

}
```

Here is my code, I would expect my anser to be 7 (as 3 + 4). However the console outputs NaN. I need to find a way in which I can grab both files in the same javascript file to use in my other functions that I have in my .js file

Answer (score 0):

You should add your response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: got the same NaN when added FILE1.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); after the .open line

Comment: When you can run chrome disable web security, can you take a right output ? 
In Windows, paste this command in run window => chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security